# Get row percentile from order by ranking

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the percentile value of a row.

For example, if there are 100 rows, and a row is at position 50 based on the `ORDER BY`, then it should be 50th percentile (I think). Something like row index based on the order divided by the total number of rows.

The following gets the row rank:

```
SET @rank=0; 
SELECT id,code,@rank:=@rank+1 AS rank 
FROM images 
ORDER BY 
    (select avg(value) 
     from ratings 
     where image_id = images.id and type = 1) 
DESC
```

How would I get the percentile for a single row? (`WHERE id = :id`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only missing piece of the puzzle was the total number of rows in the resulting set:

```
SET @rank=0; 
SELECT id,code,@rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,
       100.0 * @rank / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images) AS percentile
FROM images 
ORDER BY 
    (select avg(value) 
     from ratings 
     where image_id = images.id and type = 1) 
DESC
```

Comment: I think it's `ASC` now if it's percentile, but thanks a lot! Only issue is, it doesn't work when using `WHERE` to get a single row

Comment: If you're filtering your results in the main select, you must use the same filtering criteria within the `SELECT COUNT(*)` subquery!